# New line characters Desktop vs Server - Updated

Tags: javascript

I am trying to catch new line characters with JavaScript.But here is the catch.

For example with a string as argument to my function;

`s = "some_text_with_a_\n_new_line";
Document.write(s);`

It will get detected by my script;

Now if I get my text from a textarea and I press enter to produce a line break. It will get detected and interpreted as \n. Now the texte area and the working script are on my desktop. Window 10.

When i upload it to the server (IIS 7 on windows "Godaddy") its not working anymore so I have try some variant  like \r\n , \r non of them work. Actually it dont mater much to me cause all I'm looking for is the escaping .

Here is a piece of script I use to find them:

```
        nex = string.indexOf(tokout[i]);  // where tokout = '\n'
        spacer = 1;                       //spacer to escape found token
        spc = tokin.length;               ///last token
        if(tokin[spc-1] === '\n'){ //// spacer to set cursor after token
          spacer = 2;
        }

        BBCode = input.substr(curseur,nex+spacer); // we have bbcode
```

The script is working on my desktop but on the server I can't get the line break!

How it works:

I get the position of the \n.
Set the position of my cursor right after it.
and what is in BBcode is the line break.

For some reason it only work on my PC not the server. So I'm thinking it has to be the way break line are interpreted by the server!

Comment: they are not interpreted as a space, space characters are collapsed into a single space, which means the newlines in your source appear as a space character, unless you are using styles that tell the browser to leave newlines as newlines.

Comment: As to why it appears as a space, think of how HTML works normally; if you create a new line it doesn't interpret that as a new line...it just truncates that. Only certain HTML tags like a <br /> will trigger a new line.

Comment: Updated my post cause I think that the \n is not interpreted the same way in the browser, from the textarea

Answer (score 4):

They are not interpretted as space. They are displayed as space. To display AS IS you could surround with a pre tag. e.g.

```
document.write('<pre>' + s + '</pre>');
```

Also, you should be looking for \n not //n

i.e. `s.indexOf('\n')`

if you are trying to output to a document, you could replace the `\n` with `<br/>`

e.g. `s.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')`

Comment: Dont i have to escape it because indexOf('\n\') is giving me an error unexpected token:

Comment: second \ was a typo. refresh - sorry!

Comment: ok thank you I'm working on that. the thing is that i do a s.replace only once I found it. cause its not the only thing I'm replacing so i search the text for token that have been tagged for replacement.

Comment: use a regex: s.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>)  .. will update answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see line break in HTML you have to use `<br />` HTML tag:

```
document.write("some_text_with_a_<br />_new_line");
```

However in javascript `\n` is a valid line break character. For example when you use console.log or alert you will see 2 lines:

```
console.log("some_text_with_a_\n_new_line");
alert("some_text_with_a_\n_new_line");
```